# userKey params undefined

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm getting this error from **index.js**

```
4:24:58.455 PM
sendNotification
Function execution took 412 ms, finished with status: 'error'
4:24:58.444 PM
sendNotification
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'userKey' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:28:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:728:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
4:24:58.044 PM
sendNotification
 Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
```

**This is my index.js file:**

```
/*
 * Functions SDK : is required to work with firebase functions.
 * Admin SDK : is required to send Notification using functions.
 */

'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


/*
 * 'OnWrite' works as 'addValueEventListener' for android. It will fire the function
 * everytime there is some item added, removed or changed from the provided 'database.ref'
 * 'sendNotification' is the name of the function, which can be changed according to
 * your requirement
 */

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{userKey}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {


  /*
   * You can store values as variables from the 'database.ref'
   * Just like here, I've done for 'user_id' and 'notification'
   */

  const userKey = event.params.userKey;
  const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification from : ', userKey);

  /*
   * Stops proceeding to the rest of the function if the entry is deleted from database.
   * If you want to work with what should happen when an entry is deleted, you can replace the
   * line from "return console.log.... "
   */

  if(!event.data.val()){

    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);

  }

  /*
   * 'fromUser' query retreives the ID of the user who sent the notification
   */

  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${userKey}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

  return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

    console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);

    /*
     * The we run two queries at a time using Firebase 'Promise'.
     * One to get the name of the user who sent the notification
     * another one to get the devicetoken to the device we want to send notification to
     */

    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/Name`).once('value');
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${userKey}/Device Token`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

      const userName = result[0].val();
      const token_id = result[1].val();

      /*
       * We are creating a 'payload' to create a notification to be sent.
       */

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title : "New Friend Request",
          body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
          icon: "default",
          click_action : "com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
        },
        data : {
          from_user_id : from_user_id
        }
      };

      /*
       * Then using admin.messaging() we are sending the payload notification to the token_id of
       * the device we retreived.
       */

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

        return console.log('This was the notification Feature');

      });

    });

  });

});
```

In my chat app, I want to send notification from one user to another, but I'm not getting any notification, aermiolso showing error in firebase logs when I deploy the project from terminal. How can I solve this problem? please help me as I don't know JS!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
 * Functions SDK : is required to work with firebase functions.
 * Admin SDK : is required to send Notification using functions.
 */

'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


/*
 * 'OnWrite' works as 'addValueEventListener' for android. It will fire the function
 * everytime there is some item added, removed or changed from the provided 'database.ref'
 * 'sendNotification' is the name of the function, which can be changed according to
 * your requirement
 */

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{userKey}/{notification_id}').onWrite((snap, event) => {


  /*
   * You can store values as variables from the 'database.ref'
   * Just like here, I've done for 'user_id' and 'notification'
   */

  const userKey = event.params.userKey;
  const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification from : ', userKey);

  /*
   * Stops proceeding to the rest of the function if the entry is deleted from database.
   * If you want to work with what should happen when an entry is deleted, you can replace the
   * line from "return console.log.... "
   */

  if(!event.data.val()){

    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);

  }

  /*
   * 'fromUser' query retreives the ID of the user who sent the notification
   */

  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${userKey}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

  return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

    console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);

    /*
     * The we run two queries at a time using Firebase 'Promise'.
     * One to get the name of the user who sent the notification
     * another one to get the devicetoken to the device we want to send notification to
     */

    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/Name`).once('value');
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${userKey}/Device Token`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

      const userName = result[0].val();
      const token_id = result[1].val();

      /*
       * We are creating a 'payload' to create a notification to be sent.
       */

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title : "New Friend Request",
          body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
          icon: "default",
          click_action : "com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
        },
        data : {
          from_user_id : from_user_id
        }
      };

      /*
       * Then using admin.messaging() we are sending the payload notification to the token_id of
       * the device we retreived.
       */

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

        return console.log('This was the notification Feature');

      });

    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Sorry I’m writing from my phone and not easily able to write the whole sentence of code

Comment: My dear, I don't know any single line of JS language. Please edit your answer and completely paste the index.js file.

Comment: Alright, I’ll do that as soon as I get to a computer.

Comment: Did you try it? Was it helpful?